# Assign different icons to specific level of the game on the level selection screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement a logic that would assign text and picture to a specific level.
The structure that I have right now is stateless widget that contains list view, where onTap for Animated box logic is stored.
Levels description placed in another file.

```
    child: ListView(
            children: [
              for (final level in gameLevels)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    
                    enabled: playerProgress.highestLevelReached >=
                        level.number - 1,
                    onTap: 
                    () {
                      final audioController = context.read<AudioController>();
                      audioController.playSfx(SfxType.buttonTap);
                      GoRouter.of(context).go('/play/session/${level.number}');
                      
                    },
                    // leading: Text(level.number.toString()),
                    title: AnimatedContainer(
                        width: 317,
                        height: 78,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0XFFFEF4DF),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            offset: Offset(6, 6),
                            blurRadius: 15,
                            color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                            spreadRadius: 1,
                          ),
                          BoxShadow(
                            offset: Offset(-6, -6),
                            blurRadius: 15,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 249, 235),
                            spreadRadius: 1,
                          ),
                        ],
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                        child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                        Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/iphoneicon.png'),),
                        Text('Level ${level.number}', 
                        style: 
                        TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25, 
                        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,),),
                     ],) ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ],
          ),
```

So I wonder if it would be better to create stateful widget in the same file and check if level == 1 then show picture or text or should it be better implemented in the onTap  that I already have as a statement. Will be very thankful for any advice.